# Parameterizing types by integers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, kdtree, algebraic-data-types, higher-kinded-types

I am trying to make some Haskell types which are parametrized not by types but by elements of a type, specifically, integers.  For instance, a (linear-algebra) vector in R^2 and a vector in R^3 are different typed objects.  Specifically, I am writing a K-D tree in Haskell and I want to parametrize my data-structure by a positive integer so a 3-D tree and 4-D tree have different type.

I've tried to parametrize my tree by tuples, but it didn't seem to be going anywhere (and it seems somewhat unlikely this can be pushed through, especially since it doesn't seem that triples or anything bigger are even functors (and I don't know any way to say like, instance HomogeneousTuple a => Functor a).  I want to do something like this:

```
data (TupleOfDoubles a) => KDTree a b = ... ---so in a 3DTree a is (Double,Double,Double)
```

that would be nice, or something like this would be equally good

```
data KDTree Int a = ... -- The Int is k, so KDTree has kind Int -> * -> *
```

Does anybody know if either of these effects are workable or reasonable?

Thanks
-Joseph

Comment: a side-note, you might be interested in some of the literature on dependent types, which is a more general sort of functions from values to types: I enjoyed http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~peterd/papers/DependentTypesAtWork.pdf

Comment: thanks Amos, that seems something I can use

Answer (score 5):

There's a GHC extension being worked on called [TypeNats](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeNats), which would be exactly what you want. However the milestone for that is currently set to be 7.4.1 according to [the ticket](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4385), so that'll be a bit of a wait still.

Until that extension is available, the only thing you can do is encode the dimension using types. For example something along these lines might work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
class MyTypeNat a where
    toInteger :: a -> Integer

data Zero
data Succ a

instance MyTypeNat Zero where
    toInteger _ = 0

instance MyTypeNat a => MyTypeNat (Succ a) where
    toInteger _ = toInteger (undefined :: a) + 1

data KDTree a b = -- ...

dimension :: forall a b. MyTypeNat a => KDTree a b -> Integer
dimension = toInteger (undefined :: a)
```

The downside of an approach like this is of course that you have to write something like `KDTree (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))) Foo` instead of `KDTree 3 Foo`.

Comment: Sure, but then a type Three = Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)) will help.

Comment: If you are only going to use small numbers, you might just as well encode them directly: data One / data Two / data Three / data Four - it's easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

sepp2k's answer shows the basic approach to doing this.  In fact, a lot of the work has already been done.

Type-level number packages

- [natural-number](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/natural-number) and [type-level-natural-number](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-level-natural-number)
- [numtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numtype)
- [type-level](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-level)

Stuff using type-level encodings of natural numbers (examples)

- [Vec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Vec)
- [Dimensional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional)
- [llvm](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm)
- [ForSyDe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ForSyDe)

Unfortunately something like this:

```
data KDTree Int a = ...
```

isn't really possible.  The final type (constructed by `KDTree`) depends on the value of the Int, which requires a feature called dependent types.  Languages like Agda and Epigram support this, but not Haskell.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Vec seems like the simplest possible example for me to learn how to do this.

Comment: Yes, Vec is probably the simplest, then Dimensional.  llvm and ForSyDe are more complex, although I think they both basically just implement the same thing as Vec.